# How to perform one-hot encoding on both train and test dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was having a problem using the model to make predictions on my testing input, but the number of features does not match between these datasets. Therefore, I decided to follow a method on an article about how to overcome this mismatch problem, which is combining the two datasets and the doing encoding on the combined dataset. Here is how I doing the combining steps:

```
data_raw = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)

#Exploring the Columns in the Data Set
pd.Series(data_raw.columns) 
pd.Series(data_raw.dtypes)

data_raw.describe(include='all')

data_raw['collision_type'] = data_raw.loc[0:, 'collision_type'].replace('?', 'Unknown')
data_raw['property_damage'] = data_raw.loc[0:, 'property_damage'].replace('?', 'Unknown')

data_raw.isnull().sum()

dropping_columns = ['months_as_customer', 'age', 'policy_number', 'policy_bind_date', 'policy_annual_premium', 'insured_zip', 
                    'capital_gains', 'capital_loss', 'total_claim_amount', 'injury_claim', 'property_claim', 'vehicle_claim',
                   'auto_year']

data_cleaned = data_raw.drop(dropping_columns, axis=1)
data_cleaned_dropped = data_cleaned.drop(['fraud_reported'], axis=1)



test_raw = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)

test_raw.describe(include='all')

test_raw['collision_type'] = data_raw.loc[0:, 'collision_type'].replace('?', 'Unknown')

test_raw['property_damage'] = data_raw.loc[0:, 'property_damage'].replace('?', 'Unknown')

test_raw.isnull().sum()

test_dropped = test_raw.drop(dropping_columns, axis=1)


data_cleaned_dropped['train'] = 1
test_dropped['train'] = 0

combined = pd.concat([data_cleaned_dropped, test_dropped])

df = pd.get_dummies(combined, drop_first=True)

combined = pd.concat([combined,df], axis=1)

train_df = combined[combined["train"] == 1] ##This is where the error happened
test_df = combined[combined["train"] == 0]
train_df.drop(["train"], axis=1, inplace=True) 
test_df.drop(["train"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This is the error I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-165-e6d470e94433>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/BusinessUser/Downloads/insurance_claim_fraud_detection-master/insurance_claim_fraud_detection.py', wdir='C:/Users/BusinessUser/Downloads/insurance_claim_fraud_detection-master')

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/BusinessUser/Downloads/insurance_claim_fraud_detection-master/insurance_claim_fraud_detection.py", line 139, in <module>
    train_df = combined[combined["train"] == 1]

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2967, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_frame(key)

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3067, in _getitem_frame
    return self.where(key)

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 9276, in where
    cond, other, inplace, axis, level, errors=errors, try_cast=try_cast

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 9123, in _where
    axis=block_axis,

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 557, in where
    return self.apply("where", **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 436, in apply
    kwargs[k] = obj.reindex(b_items, axis=axis, copy=align_copy)

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 221, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3961, in reindex
    return super().reindex(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4514, in reindex
    axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3843, in _reindex_axes
    columns, method, copy, level, fill_value, limit, tolerance

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3891, in _reindex_columns
    allow_dups=False,

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4577, in _reindex_with_indexers
    copy=copy,

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1251, in reindex_indexer
    self.axes[axis]._can_reindex(indexer)

  File "C:\Users\BusinessUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3362, in _can_reindex
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

For your information, my training dataset have a final column for the prediction result, while my testing dataset also have such columns but all values are NULL. I just want to know if anyone had face the same problem in the past, so I could gain some experience how to overcome this mismatch problem by any means.

Also, I just want to ask if in order to make the data concatenation works, does the columns between train dataset and test input must match? I just think that the predicted result column does not exist in the test input so how does this thing work? Any comment is much appreciated.

Thank you guys very much for helping me out!

Comment: Most likely it is because `combined` has more than 2 columns named `train`. Nevertheless, it is difficult to exactly pinpoint the problem without having the same dataset to reproduce the error

Comment: Hi @YohanesGultom, I am pretty sure that the combined dataset has only 2 columns named train as I created above, unless the get_dummies function produced more features from these columns. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. I mean *more than 1 column*. Basically you can't have duplicate columns

Comment: Hi @YohanesGultom, thank you very much for your suggestion. I indeed solved the problem from it.